# Generating points from a standard Gaussian

Tags: statistics, matlab, signal-processing, research

I'm new to Gaussian distributions and I'm trying to generate say, $ N$ points from a $ M$ dimensional standard gaussian. What does this mean? How would I do this in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how in [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html). In general, you can generate a uniform random variable on [0,1] then feed it into the inverse CDF (i.e,$\Phi^{-1}$) for the gaussian to get a random variable.

Comment: What does $M$ dimensions of the standard gaussian mean? In 
[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html) how would you specify you need the distribution from M dimensions of the standard gaussian?

Comment: It would be a vector-valued random variable. So you draw $N$ samples of size M from the Normal(0,1). Each set of M draws constitutes one point from a standard M-dimensional gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, if you want to generate N samples of an 1xM Gaussian random vector, so that its components follow a multivariate Gaussian distribution with 1xM mean vector `mu` and MxM covariance matrix `sigma`, use

```
samples = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,N);
```

This gives an NxM matrix, `samples`, where each row is an 1xM sample vector.